# Understanding how to work with 2 branches (master, staging) with Github?

Tags: git, github, git-workflow

I have a repo on Github with 2 branches a "**master**" and "**staging**".  I use the "**staging**" branch to make all updates that I first test on on my **test site**.  Then once the updates are ready I merge with "**master**" then push to my **live site**.

I know if I make changes to my local copy, I can push this to my "**staging**" branch and it will only affect my **test site**.

However, what happens if I need to make a change just to my current "**master**" branch so I can push to my **live site** before all my "**staging**" updates are ready.

I already changed the files on my local copy which is in sync with my "**staging**" branch, how do I make a change so it only affects my "**master**" branch?

Do I have to have 2 copies of my local files on my PC, one for "**staging**" and one for "**master**"?

Thank you!

Comment: Checkout master and do the change, commit it, and push?

Comment: In addition to @LasseV.Karlsen proper steps, if master moves since you've last merged staging into it, you should merge those master changes into staging and test to make sure nothing breaks before merging back into master. Or else you could have issues with your live site. (and or miss fixes if you accidently fix a merge conflict incorrectly).

Comment: I think that the [tag:git-workflow] tag would be of use for you to peruse.

Answer (score -1):

Just make changes to your master branch then do

`git add .`

`git commit -m "your message"`

`git push`

it will only update your master branch. Then check out your staging branch and  do `git merge master` to merge back those changes from master to staging.